# Specific SQL Query AVG and Count

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the below table in my DB

[image: My Table]

I need ONE select query in order to get:

1. Total duration for each A where Type=1... type=2... type=3
2. Count(A) for each type (where type-1... type =2 and type=3

So my result would be like this:

A          Count of Type1       Count of Type 2        AVG(Duration) Type1      AVG(Duration)Type2

---

1029         20                           15                                   200                                   156

What is the exact query to get the above result?

Comment: "What is the exact query to get the above result?" seems like a request to do your work for you. What have you tried? What it is you you're missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what are you looking for:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a,
       SUM(CASE WHEN type = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY a) AS count_of_type_1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN type = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY a) AS count_of_type_2,
       SUM(CASE WHEN type = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY a) AS count_of_type_3,
       AVG(CASE WHEN type = 1 THEN duratuion ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY a) AS avg_duration_of_type_1,
       AVG(CASE WHEN type = 2 THEN duratuion ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY a) AS avg_duration_of_type_2,
       AVG(CASE WHEN type = 3 THEN duratuion ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY a) AS avg_duration_of_type_3,
       SUM(CASE WHEN type = 1 THEN duratuion ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY a) AS total_duration_of_type_1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN type = 2 THEN duratuion ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY a) AS total_duration_of_type_2,
       SUM(CASE WHEN type = 3 THEN duratuion ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY a) AS total_duration_of_type_3
FROM your_table
```

Comment: YOU CHAMP BRO :) Thank you so much @Kirill Kin

Comment: You are welcome, Mohammad!

Comment: @MohammadKASSAB, thank you!